# Create maven repository in mercurial repository

Tags: maven, mercurial, repository, release

Is it possible to create a maven repository inside a mercurial repo?

I've done the same thing in a google code repository with SVN a few years ago using the wagon-svn extension.

```
<build>
    [...]
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.wagon-svn</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-svn</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>googlecode</id>
            <url>svn:https://[...].googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</build>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is why not using a repo Manager instead?

Comment: I couldn't find any free private repo Manager service.

Comment: Is this an open source project? If yes just use the [Maven Central](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html).

Comment: It'not, a freemium service would be perfect, since I intend to pay for it in the future.

Comment: I think you should take a look @  [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)